# How to list taxonomy terms in reverse order?

Tags: taxonomy

Hi I have taxonomy terms that needs to be displayed in reverse order.
I have parent term"Arizona" and sub term "phoenix" and needs to be displayed like "Phoenix, Arizona" on the page.

do you know how this can be done?

[image]

Comment: What happens when there is a duplicate city name? https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/most-common-town-and-city-names-in-the-u-s-a.html